# Заменить строку с кодом

Tags: jquery

Есть `textarea`, который содержит в себе строку кода

Нужно заменить этот код на, допустим, "кря".

Если делать это так:

```js
var replacer = $('textarea').val()
  .replace(/<div class="class" onclick="$(this).replace('bla-bla','mda blya');">/g, 'Кря');

$('textarea').val(replacer);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows="14" cols="50">
    ...
    ...
    &lt;div class="class" onclick="$(this).replace('bla-bla','wooow');"&gt;
    ...
    ...
</textarea>
```

То ничего не работает.
Как быть?

Comment: Не работает скорее всего из-за того, что содержит в себе JS/JQ код, но это лишь мои догадки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function replaceTest() {
  var value = "<div class=\"class\" onclick=\"$(this).replace('bla-bla','wooow');\">";
  var replacer = $('textarea').val().replace(value, 'Кря');
  $('textarea').val(replacer);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea style="width:400px;height:100px;">
...
...
&lt;div class="class" onclick="$(this).replace('bla-bla','wooow');"&gt;
...
...
</textarea>
<br> Нужно заменить этот код на, допустим, "кря".
<button onclick="replaceTest()">Replace</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот пример где вы сами вводите на что менять.

```js
$('.btn').on('click', (e)=> {
    const replacer = $('.newVal').val();
    $('textarea').val(replacer);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea>
...
...
&lt;div class="class" onclick="$(this).replace('bla-bla','wooow');"&gt;
...
...
</textarea>
<div> Заменить значение 
<button class='btn'>Заменить</button>
<div><input type='text' class='newVal' placeholder='на какое менять?'></div>
</div>
```